# Warning: Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-valet

I am using Laravel valet for a while, but now I started getting errors:

```
Warning: Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: 
Warning: Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0/cli/valet.php
```

and it can't load local web applications anymore (with .test at the end).
I tried updating valet and run again valet install but get this:

```
PHP Warning:  Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: 
Warning: Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0/cli/valet.php`
```

I have macos and valet.

Have someone ideas about what I can try out?

Comment: May be mongodb extension is enabled not only in php.ini but also in valet. You can search in valet for mongodb module.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Temporarily comment out extension=mongodb.so or extension=mongodb in your  php.ini, if problem goes out then we should search for duplicate enabling mongodb extension in valet files.

Comment: ok but how to find them an remove duplicates?

Comment: I think that is a problem with your PHP version or even valet version. Can you try upgrade/update PHP and valet?

Comment: fixed in a way to remove '/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini' file but now getting 502 error even valet installed and looks work ok and added link to app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922673/valet-502-bad-gateway